# being positive "deceitful" to encourage someone

Tags: word-usage

Some friend told me the word "deceitful" usually has a negative connotation.

Assume Alice's grammar is bad. Her teacher tells that her grammar is good to encourage her. Provided Alice's bad grammar is a fact, Her teacher tells a lie. Although the lie is to encourage Alice and hurts nobody.

Could I say the following?

> The teacher is being **deceitful** to encourage her students.

where "deceitful" is being used as a positive word.

which means lots of adjectives that have negative connotations could be used as positive words.

Could someone please give a hint about **the rules/conventions of it**? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it could hurt her, by making her assume that her grammar is good enough, so that she feels that she does not need to practice / work on it, and thus she will not improve.

Nevertheless, I would not use deceitful in this case, as the teacher was trying to encourage her.  Similar for when you are trying not to discourage someone, or not hurt someone's feelings.

I would say the teacher "told a little white lie" or "sugar-coated the truth"